# Map the text box value in google custom search api URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i want to pass the 'query' in the url .i.e in q=..how to do that?

```
String query= request.getParameter("query");
System.out.println(query);
response.sendRedirect("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1key=AIzaSyDvKmDisCOXJzP7JF24pvXvb2-IwgiDYek&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=cars&alt=json");
```

Comment: here i have put the query in the URL as 'cars' but i want to add it from the text box named 'query'

Comment: check the last part of the URL its &q=cars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** Create a HTML form

```
<form action="/googleGateway" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="query"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**2** create a `Servlet` and map it to `/googleGateway`

from doPost()

```
String query= request.getParameter("query");
//valdate query
System.out.println(query);
response.sendRedirect("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1key=AIzaSyDvKmDisCOXJzP7JF24pvXvb2-IwgiDYek&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q="+ query +"&alt=json");
```

---

**See Also**

- [`Servlet`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are going to append the query after the URL link. This way you can not pass the the query, as query would be containing white spaces, and spaces are not allowed in URL formate.

You may pass Query in post form.